# Run multiple versions of services with docker compose simultaneously

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy different versions of an app simultaneously on the same host.

For example, with file `compose.yaml` such as:

```
services:
  db:
    name: my_project.$VERSION.db
    image: db:$VERSION
    networks:
      - my_bridge
  app:
    name: my_project.$VERSION.app
    image: app:$VERSION
    networks:
      - my_bridge

networks:
  my_bridge:
    name: my_bridge_$VERSION
```

I'd like the following two commands to run to independent versions of my app and db, each communicating with their own network:

```
VERSION=test1 docker compose up -d
VERSION=test2 docker compose up -d
```

The first command does bring up the expected containers `my_project.test1.db` and `my_project.test1.app` and the network `my_bridge_test1`. But the second command tears down the previous container and replaces them with `my_project.test2.db` and `my_project.test2.app`.

Is there a way to deploy two parallel versions of an app with docker compose from the same project (but, different branches for example) and on the same host ?

Comment: maybe using the `--project-name` option fixes the naming conflict you are having with the service and network name

Comment: Also note that the project name is part of the names Compose generates automatically for containers and networks; you do not need to specify `container_name:` or `networks: { name: }` and in fact omitting those will make it a little easier to run multiple copies concurrently.